# Need to call from an object/method that intakes scanner and print it

Tags: java

I need to be able to take in "Name Age School GPA and highest letter grade recieved". However, I am having difficulty performing this seemingly simple task. Please help!!

```
package schoolinfo;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SchoolInfo {
void stu(String name, String
        age, String school, double gpa, char letter){

    System.out.println("You, " + name +", are " + age+ " years old and go to " + school + " Where you have a gpa of " + gpa + "and have recieved a highest letter grade of " + letter);

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    SchoolInfo student = new SchoolInfo();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean onoff = true;

    while(onoff){
          String countAge = " ";
    String countGPA = " ";
    String countName = " ", countSchool = " ";
    String countLetter = " ";
    String first;
    first = scan.nextLine();
        if(first.equals("quit")){
            break;
        }


        first = scan.nextLine();
       countName = first.substring(0, first.indexOf(" ", 2));
       countAge = first.substring(first.indexOf(" ", 2), first.indexOf(" ", 2));
       countSchool = first.substring(first.indexOf(" ", first.indexOf(" ", 2)), first.indexOf(" ", 2));
        countGPA = scan.nextDouble();
       countLetter = scan.next().charAt(first.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);           
      System.out.println("test");
        student.stu(countName, countAge, countSchool, countGPA, countLetter);

    }
}

}
```

I guess I need to add more details to post this, but please help!!! TIA!!

Comment: Telling us the problem that you're having might help...

Comment: You are right that you did not provide enough details. What exactly do you have problems with?

Comment: `countGPA` is declared a string. Why are you using `nextDouble()`

Answer (score 1):

The parameters you are passing to `stu` don't match the parameters you've declared in the class.

```
void stu(String name, String
        age, String school, double gpa, char letter)
```

In you're main you've declared the variables as `String`.

```
String countAge = " ";
String countGPA = " ";
String countName = " ", countSchool = " ";
String countLetter = " ";
```

But you then try to retrieve input for `countGPA` as a double.

```
countGPA = scan.nextDouble();
```

You should probably declare `countGPA` as a `double` and either cast `countLetter` to a `char` or change the class method to accept it as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you made a small mistake ,because you use

```
countGPA = scan.nextDouble();
```

with string value and this method reads double value

so you have to change type of "countGPA" to double instead of String

```
double countGPA ;
```

and use

```
countLetter = scan.next().charAt(first.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

with string value too ,so you need to change type of "countLetter" to char instead of String

```
char countLetter;
```

i think it will work as you want

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. This code ended up working

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package schoolinfo;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author jpowell1225
 */
public class SchoolInfo {
    void stu(String name, int
            age, String school, double gpa, char letter){
     //   System.out.println("test");
        System.out.println("You, " + name +", are " + age+ " years old and go to " + school + " where you have a gpa of " + gpa + " and have recieved a highest letter grade of " + letter);
        
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        SchoolInfo student = new SchoolInfo();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean onoff = true;
      
        while(onoff){
              int countAge = 0;
        double countGPA = 0.0;
        String countName = " ", countSchool = " ";
        char countLetter = 'a';
        String first;
        first = scan.next();
            if(first.equals("quit")){
                break;
            }
            
            
            //first = scan.nextLine();
           countName = first;//.substring(0, first.indexOf(" ", 2));
           countAge = scan.nextInt();
           countSchool = scan.next();
            countGPA = scan.nextDouble();
           countLetter = scan.next().charAt(first.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);           
        //  System.out.println("test");
            student.stu(countName, countAge, countSchool, countGPA, countLetter);
      
        }
    }
    
}
```